# Problem with same hostname and domain

Tags: server, hostname

When I was setting up my production server the hostname was same as the name of one domain that wasn't planned to be used, but now I have to use this domain name and files are stored in `/var/www` directory (root directory) and I have trouble with permissions.

I was thinking about changing the hostname of the server to another one and creating a new domain through `ispconfig` (`/var/www/client#/domain`). Will this solve the problem with pointing to `/var/www` when going to the domain address, or do I have to use another approach?

My server is Ubuntu 12.04 configured with [this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-12.04-lts-apache2-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3).

Comment: Are the domain name and file permission issues related in any way?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by changing `ServerName` in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` to the name in the DNS record. That solved the misconfiguration problem.

Comment: might I suggest naming your webserver `www.example.com`?

Comment: I don't think that naming server "www.example.com" is good idea for production.